# conflicting distributed object modifiers on return type in implementation of 'release' in Singleton class

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode4.2

I have recently upgraded to Xcode 4.2 and its  started to give me so many semantic warnings with my code...

one of them is "conflicting distributed object modifiers on return type in implementation of 'release'" in my singleton class..

I read somewhere about - (oneway void)release; to release this warning but once i put that in my code i start to getting compile error as "Duplicate declaration of release" not sure why and if you try to find the second declaration it shows in this line

SYNTHESIZE_SINGLETON_FOR_CLASS(GlobalClass);

Update: This is the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7379470/singleton-release-method-produces-warning)   where it explained about - (oneway void)release;

how to get rid of this warning "conflicting distributed object modifiers on return type in implementation of release" ? and why its happening ?

Comment: how to get rid of this warning "conflicting distributed object modifiers on return type in implementation of 'release"

Comment: is `oneway` specified both on the declaration and on the definition of the method?

Comment: So put it in both. GCC is complaining because your definition doesn't match your declaration. If you haven't declared `-release` in your class, do so. (Though this raises the question of why you're overriding `-release`.)

Comment: warning appears even if i don't override the release..

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The post you link to contains the solution to the problem in the title and explains why it  happened to you.

However, from reading your question it appears that your new issue is caused by mis-applying the great advice in that post's answer. I am fairly certain you *added* the line

```
- (oneway void) release {}
```

in your .m file rather than amending your existing

```
- (void) release {
```

line with the extra word "oneway".

This would be why you get "Duplicate declaration of release". Yes, this is confusing because it's a duplicate definition that is invisibly creating the duplicate declaration. But I've just tried doing it your wrong way, and I get that "duplicate declaration" message.

I get the impression, perhaps wrongly, that you didn't realise you actually had a release method, particularly when you think adding the line will "release this warning".

Don't take all errors too literally, and always try to think what someone might really mean as it's often different from what they say, but do try and understand what is in your code, even in the classes you've taken off the shelf.

And to address other questions raised, the reason you're overriding release is because it is a singleton which is not usually released. You probably only have a definition in your code, which will suffice.

What Jonathan Grynspan has to say about specifying on both the declaration and the definition is broadly valid (and indeed the root of the issue) but it's important to recognise that in this specific case, the declaration is by Apple's foundation code which has changed.

So, if it's not clear already, **amend the line that XCode finds problem with to include the word oneway**.

Comment: Just to clarify, in this *specific* case (when the error appears on `SYNTHESIZE_SINGLETON_FOR_CLASS`) the place to make the modification to `release` is inside of the definition of the `SYNTHESIZE_SINGLETON_FOR_CLASS` macro, which should be declared in `SynthesizeSingleton.h`.

Comment: That's good additional information. When I said "the line that XCode finds problem with", I assumed that a click or two in XCode would take most people to the right specific place, but it is good to clarify exactly where this change is made in this specific case.